# ESP32,ESP8266, AND ESP8266 NODE MCU not working

Tags: arduino, port, esp8266, esp32

1.I started with esp. 32  i used arduino IDE it only showed COM1 in PORTS. when i was uploading the code i pressed the boot button when connecting..... appears in the window but still an error (timeout....) occurs and code doesn't upload.
i installed the drivers but whenever i plugged in the usb cable a notification pops up that the computer doesn't recognize the device. i installed ch341 but it says the the drivers are preinstalled.

same problem appear with esp8266 node mcu.

Then using the same cable I started working with esp8266 no error popped up  it had two options in PORT COM1 and COM4 I choose COM4 and I uploaded the  blink code. it worked fine but after that i upload the WIFI SCAN code it started showing same problem as esp32... i disconnected it and connected again error popped up that it doesn't recognized by computer. and furthermore  now it only shows com1 in ports option and when I press flash button the code doesn't get uploaded it shows timed out error. i disconnected and connected many times but it doesn't working.

Comment: If you saw a warning which said "device is not recognized", then the problem is on the hardware connection. Try to use different usb cable or use different port on the computer. Your title sure is misleading. I come here because i thought the culprit was the ESP. It seems not. May be the issue is on ESP usb connector, however it is still pcb problem, not the ESP it self.

Answer (score 0):

are you setting like this??
this is my setting on the arduino

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I mean you can try to install the esp32 USB port library CP210x_Universal_Windows_Driver.exe.

Answer (score 0):

if your system does not detect esp8266 or NodeMCU boards while you installed all possible drivers, as mentioned in this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/issues/3551) **change your USB wire** cause the wire maybe is for just charging and not transferring data! 
changing it worked for me!